# Create a template template function in header and implementation file

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, template-templates

So I have the class PolyLine which I am trying to genericize to allow stl containers, like list or vector, to act as the class container. I am trying to use a template template function to do this:

```
template<typename T, template<typename, typename> class Container, typename alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class PolyLine : public CAD::Shape {
private:
  size_t _n_points; //Number of points
  Container<T, alloc> _pline;
public:

  //Constructors
  PolyLine(size_t, double);
  PolyLine(const PolyLine&); //Copy constructor

  //Print
  void print();

  //Operator overload functions
  PolyLine& operator = (const PolyLine&);


};
```

And I am trying to implement the functions in the implementation file like this:

```
#include "PolyLine.hpp"

template<typename T, template<typename,typename> class Container, typename alloc = std::allocator<T>>
PolyLine<Container<T, alloc>>::PolyLine(size_t size, double distance) :  Shape(), _n_points(size) {
};
```

This does not work and apparently I need to fix something in the declaration of `PolyLine<Container<T,alloc>>`, but I am not sure what. *Edit: the error is get is "PolyLine: too few template arguments".

Comment: What does *"This does not work"* mean? Also in most cases you need to define/implement the functions in the header file as well

Comment: This does not work = I get the error "too few template arguments" so it can't match to an existing declaration.  And I am not sure what you mean by define/implement the function in the header file? Is that something specific for template template classes? Because normally you declare in the header file and implement in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specialised `PolyLine` for `Container<T, alloc>` so the only constructor definitions we can provide are those for the default specialisation (`PolyLine<T, Container, alloc>`):

```
template<typename T, template<typename,typename> class Container, typename alloc>
PolyLine<T, Container, alloc>::PolyLine(size_t size, double distance) 
: Shape(), _n_points(size) 
{
}
```